# style Items in ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I am trying to set a list of Items in my View,like that:

[image]

but the problem is that I get this instead:

[image]

this is my code:

```
    <Grid Background="#e6e7e8" >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
             </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Background="#6b6b69" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
                <Border Grid.Column="0"   Height="39" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Image Source="images/cuisineBlanc.png" />
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Column="0"   Height="39" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="134">
                    <TextBlock Text="Cuisines" Foreground="White"/>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="Grid1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                    <ListView x:Name="listme"> 
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid >
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                                    <Image Margin="2" Height="35" Source="images/0.png"/>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                        <TextBlock Text="Cuisine" Foreground="#575855" FontSize="25" Margin="5"  />
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=nom}"  Foreground="#575855" FontSize="25" Margin="2,5,5,5" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </StackPanel>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
                                    <Image Source="images/click.png"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </Grid>
  </Grid>
```

How can I put a border thickness in each listview Item and the click.png item to the Left.Can you help me please to fix my view to be like the original
thanks for help:

Comment: Are a Cuisine and a Cuisine2 items of ListView?

Comment: no,just Cuisine 1 and Cuisine 2 are the ListView Item

Comment: and you want rows to be nearer like in an example?

Comment: yes,Sir I have used StackPanel and I have modified the orienttation but I still can't do it like the original :/

Comment: I have updated my Post Sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested your example and it shows correctly:

[image]

```
<ListView x:Name="listView">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid >
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
                            <Image Margin="2" Height="30" Width="30" Source="{StaticResource ProjectIcon}"/>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                <TextBlock Text="Cuisine" Foreground="#575855" FontSize="25" Margin="5"  />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=nom}"  Foreground="#575855" FontSize="25" Margin="2,5,5,5" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
                            <Image Source="{StaticResource ProjectIcon}" Height="30" Width="30"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```